# Execute linux command from web interface (just like in Django CMS demo generator)

Tags: php, python, bash, exec

I need to create a webpage that will generate demo similar to https://django-cms.org/en/demo/.
To generate demo, just click `Get your demo!`

I dont mind about the language, PHP or anything, as long as free and open source.

When the button clicked, it will run `/var/testing/makesite.sh`

Inside `makesite.sh`, it has code `urlnya="$thegeneratedurl"`.

If we run `echo http://$urlnya/`, it will show the full URL like `http://site1045.demosite.com/`.

After demo website has been generated, I need it display link

There are some PHP example to achieve this by `shell_exec`, but I scared if its not really safe, and I dont know how to show progress and return the demo URL just like in the Django CMS site.

Comment: Please clarify a few things: 1) What exactly is it you want to demo? Linux shell text commands? A Content Management System? Web progaming? other? 2) What's in this "generated URL"? (There is no URL at all for a Linux command, and _many many_ URLs for the demo site you reference, so I'm confused) 3) What exactly does your `makesite.sh` set up? A Linux installation? A CMS Installation? Not an installation but rather a "safe" environment? other? and 4) do you have it already working withOUT the web/HTML/remote front-end so a mythical user could sit at your own terminal and run the demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in python you have `subprocess` and `envoy` to execute `GNU/Linux` commands. You can also use `fabric` to do this.

In order to acheive this you might need to learn how to use `virtualenv` and unique `port no` has to created for each application.

This deserves a separate wrong write up. I cannot write whole source code though it is interesting.

For url part, recommend you to use random `subdomain` or different idea. You might need to store list of all previously generated values in DB or check currently running demo sites to avoid clash.

`References`

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html
https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue with shell_exec() has nothing to do with just using it. The scary risky thing is letting your user specify the string that's input to it - the string could very occasionally include all manner of weird attempts to "fool" your system and hack into it. But you don't need to do that. So long as *you* construct the string that's input to it in your own code, there should be no issue.

The string should be exactly the same thing you'd type at a Linux shell prompt. Depending on the details of what the script wants, the string that starts the script might simply be something like "/usr/local/bin/makesite.sh". Or it might also contain some parameters, like "/usr/local/bin/makesite.sh --ownername clientsname". If there are parameters, substitute them in yourself in the code you write, rather than asking the user to substitute them in for you - that way the security risk is minimal.

The result of the "echo $urlnya" in makesite.sh {and all the other output of the shell_exec() command too} will be handed to you by shell_exec() as a chunk of text to do whatever you wish with. Your code can parse it, use bits of it in your own web page, track bits of it internally, extract some sort of unique ID, and so forth. You may for example wish to place a hyperlink to that URL on the web page you're producing behind a button labelled something like {See Created Web Page}.

For the progress bar, get a widget or library that provides the functionality (but see a couple paragraphs further on:-). The ways to do it are a little weird, and cross-browser issues can be substantial, so a progress bar is one of the things where making use of somebody else's encapsulation and testing of the functionality is a really good idea. I believe a library is available from Yahoo!, and I believe JQuery includes the functionality.

The local browser/client will over and over manipulate the progress bar however it chooses for a few seconds, then "re-sync" with the server so it's displaying accurate information. One sometimes sees for example moving stripes; that movement is probably purely local and purely a "guess". But since the page will "re-sync" with the server in a few seconds to readjust its length (or even stop the stripes altogether if something has gone wrong), that should be sufficient.

Displaying a progress bar is only part of the problem though. The bigger part of the problem is *what* to display. Something on the system needs to be able to say things like "I'm 55% done". But how (or even if) makesite.sh does that I don't know. I don't know of any capabilities built in to Linux to help produce such information. You may need to run the command several times yourself to see how long it takes and what the milestones are, then create some tracker program of your own that checks for those milestones yourself. It may be more trouble than it's worth. You may wish to instead create something much simpler, say for example just some nearly-brain-dead text like "roughly estimated time to setup completion 2 more minutes" or "setup failed, please try again".